# HP-UFT : How affect an Object to a parameter?

Tags: hp-uft

I want affect an object to an  UFT parameter, for execute a test with it in Input, something like that :

```
Set objData = objOnglet.UsedRange
Parameter("test") = objData 
RunAction "fact_AC_InitEcxel", oneIteration, Parameter("test")
```

Someone has an idea ?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible (don't have UFT to test it), but did you try with `Set Parameter("test") = objData"`?

Comment: Yes I tried but it's doesn't work. I think that is not possible with UFT function or classic VBS. Maybe a FSO can handle that operation but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: In that case, I'm sorry but I'm gonna have to step out and wait for someone else to assist you, as I don't have the UFT anymore to properly try the solutions myself. Best of luck

Comment: No problem and ty for your time Victor.

Comment: It looks like you are not. Here is the link https://community.hpe.com/t5/Quality-Center-ALM-Practitioners/how-to-pass-an-object-as-an-QTP-action-output-paramater/td-p/4410318

Comment: Please dont´add an edit to your question containing the answer. Create an answer, and accept it if that answer is what solved/clarified the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done. You cannot pass objects through the `Parameter.Value` property.